# Why is tempdb consumed in this scenario? (MS SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, delete

I've found strange situation running data deletion script.
This script seems to be correct, without side effect of consuming all space in TempDB. And other processes reported problem about insufficient space for tempDB. (there is about 150 000 000 records to delete)

Unfortunately I don't know why.
Could you help me understand why all TempDB space was used?
How to improve this scritp?
It is not possible to truncate or recreating table technique, because this table is extensively used and everything have to be done on living system.

Script

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UnloadLog]
     @start_dt datetime, @end_dt datetime
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @id bigint, @idx int;
    DECLARE cursor_ids CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT [ID] FROM [Database01].[dbo].[LogTable] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE @start_dt <= [EventDate]  and [EventDate] < @end_dt;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @idx = 0;

    OPEN cursor_ids

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;


    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_ids INTO @id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM [Database01].[dbo].[LogTable] WHERE [ID] = @id;

        SET @idx = @idx + 1;

        IF @idx >=1000
        BEGIN
            COMMIT;
            SET @idx = 0;
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        END;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_ids INTO @id
    END

    COMMIT;

    CLOSE cursor_ids;  
    DEALLOCATE cursor_ids;
END
```

and procedure was run from SQL Enterprise Management Stiudio with this script

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[UnloadLog]
        @start_dt = N'2015-12-01 00:00:00',
        @end_dt = N'2016-05-01 00:00:00'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Cursors are a bit nomadic and necessarily consume tempdb space. Also depending on what operators sql chooses to process your query, additional space may be needed.

Comment: It looks like another problem. Because after killing this process huge rollback was executed by Engine. So, it looks like problem transaction within this script.

Comment: OK, I've found. This script will always work within transaction. According to MSDN documentation, instruction OPEN always starts transaction (implicitly or explicitly). So this script is not valid to remove huge amount of data.

Comment: If you're looking for a good script to batch deletes, head over here: http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Comment: How much tempdb was used by this query? What is the DDL of the table including any indexes on it?